# Discard Changes in Xcode 4 using Git retains physical files in working directory

Tags: git, xcode4

Using Git and a checked out branch in Xcode 4, when I make changes to the project (add files, edit source etc) and then discard them, the physical files are left in the working directory but are removed from the Xcode project. Is this a bug or am I misinterpreting the use of 'Discard Changes'?

Comment: I think it does not remove them in case you still need them. Most version control systems behave the same—added files are not deleted from disk when you revert the addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it using `git clean -f` and doing `git checkout -f <branch>`. Thanks anyway Jan!